# How to identify the annotation based configured transaction details?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, decompiling

When I decompile the source code of a class, which is using a transaction in a method.

I am not able to see the configured transaction details.

```
class A {

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<Object> getObjects()

{

  // related stuff

}


public List<Student> getStudents()

{

  // related stuff

}


}
```

Now if I decompile the `class A` it will not give me any hints to differentiate between these two method. It seems both are same, which they are not; one is annotation based method and one is without annotation.

Is it possible to differentiate between these methods through decompile?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using AspectJ compile time weaving, you should be able to see the woven transaction related advice in your @Transactional classes. For eg. this is what I see:

```
AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().ajc$before$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(this,
```

However this is only if you are using AspectJ compile time weaving. If you are using some other mechanism - Spring AOP or AspectJ load time weaving you will not see your byte code enhanced

Comment: Then it does not do any static byte code manipulation at all subodh. At runtime Spring creates a java dynamic proxy around the @Transaction annotated beans - here is one reference: http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/. If you are debugging, then at breakpoints you would see that the beans being referred to are the proxies.